# $\phi$ on the z-axis

Tags: linear-transformations, spherical-coordinates

I have some vector function, call it $F_a\equiv F_a(r,\theta,\phi)$ where $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the polar and azimuthal angles of a spherical coordinate system respectively. If I convert this to Cartesian coordinates using:
$$F_{a^\prime}=\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x^{a^\prime}}F_a.$$
Once I do this, my goal is to find this vector along the z-axis only. Unfortunately, while transforming to Cartesian coordinates I use the equations:
$$ \cos\phi=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, \hspace{20pt} \sin\phi=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$
Taking the limit as x and y goes to zero of the above equations yield different results, and it specifies a particular direction.

My question is, how do I define $\cos\phi$ and $\sin\phi$ on the z-axis? I know by definition that $\phi$ is undefined there, but how does this transfer to this transformation that I'm trying to do?

Please let me know if further information is needed.

Comment: Your problem is that $z$ is independent of $\phi$, so any triple $(r,0,\phi)$ is in the $z$-axis. If you tell what is excatly your vector field, maybe I will tell you more details.

Comment: @Dog_69, attaching my vector field wouldn't really help. Its about 300 terms long. The point is, many terms depend on $\cos^n\phi\sin^m\phi$, where $n$ and $m$ are integers from 0 to about 5.

Comment: The main problem I see is that if $F_\phi$ is different from $0$, then you get the term $\partial\phi/ \partial x F_x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} F_x$ (for $F_x$ for example)  and that causes problems on the $z$-axis.

Comment: @Dog_69, exactly. What I was hoping to find out was if there was a way to just get rid of $\phi$ dependence on the z-axis; like just setting $\cos\phi=\sin\phi=0$, but that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: (First two $F_x$ should be $F_\phi$ in my earlier comment). But, do you need $F$ to exist on the $z$-axes? I mean,  what happen if there is not well-defined?

Comment: If $F$ didn't exist on the z-axis, it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Then I hope you to find an answer. I have voted your question.